# system hangs on /etc/fstab after forceful restart

Tags: boot, mount, fstab

I have to following

```
fdisk -l

 Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1         2000896     3999743      999424   83  Linux
/dev/sda2   *     4194304     5242879      524288   83  Linux
/dev/sda3         5242880   167772159    81264640   83  Linux



blkid -o list

device     fs_type label    mount point    UUID
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/dev/sda1  swap    swapname (not mounted)  d4bd9a66-3249-4ee4-b92e-ea1d3c31c113
/dev/loop0 ext2             (in use)       40c4ea95-0ecc-4c51-9f3e-e49d8f62f160
/dev/sda2  ext3             (not mounted)  6f1d654f-151d-4e88-8164-b3a318753971
/dev/sda3  ext4             (not mounted)  c930ecd2-929b-4eef-90d3-60a9ee420f95
```

my `/etc/fstab` is empty 
when I restart it hangs
do I need to add the `uuid` to `etc/fstab`?

Comment: how are you sure the file is empty?

Comment: which partition is your root file system, /dev/sda3 ?

Comment: Please type `cat /etc/fstab` in a terminal window and edit your question to include the information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to specify the UUID in /etc/fstab . . .  here is what it should look like with a generic setup, single partition, mount point "/" , and a non encrypted swap.

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=c930ecd2-929b-4eef-90d3-60a9ee420f95 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=d4bd9a66-3249-4ee4-b92e-ea1d3c31c113 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Make sure your /etc/fstab file is empty. You may just need to alter the UUID(s) of the /etc/fstab entries ( if they have changed for some reason, although, it is unlikely ).

**Also,** If you use an encrypted file system, the file will be slightly different.